# Validating WinForms TextBox (in C#)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, textbox, c#-2.0

In TextBox_Leave event i need to check whether numbers entered in textbox is in serial number or not.If it is not in order then i need to display a message as "number" is missing

For example :

In textbox i have entered 3 and click tab :
I need to display message as 
"Number is not in order , number "1" and "2"  is missing "

Comment: Just one question: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: that seem pretty basic stuff, homework?

Comment: This is weird feature, I think you can redesign this feature

Answer (score 7):

I don't know whether this also works in c#2.0, this is my experience in c#3.0:

Why do you use TextBox_Leave for that? The Validating-event should be used for validating whether input is correct.

Combine using the Validating-event with using an ErrorProvider (you can just drag it from the toolbox onto the form) to set an error message: it will be displayed as a (blinking) exclamation mark in a red triangle.

An ErrorProvider can also block any submit-actions.

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to retain focus in the textbox when trying to leave (with TAB for instance) in case of some condition (missing number):

```
 private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        if (tb.Text == "3")
            tb.Focus();
    }
```

Assuming you are using a standard textbox. You could also use third party controls that where you can cancel an event (e.Cancel = true) on some condition.

Comment: Be careful with this kind of code, if you use this on multiple TextBoxes, you will create a loop of Focus you won't be able to break... An ErrorProvider is much better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a **Masked TextBox** control and set a custom property for this type of field validation.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use Validating event of the text box.

```
  private void textBox1_Validating( object sender, CancelEventArgs e )
  {
      if ( textBox1.Text == "3" )
          e.Cancel = true;
  }
```

The text-box wont loose focus until it receives a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to validate `Validating WinForms TextBox` (in C#).

1. Create a function:

   ```
   public static void ChkBlankTextBoxes(object sender, string type)
   {

       if (sender is TextBox)
       {
           TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct value value..");
               textbox.Focus();

           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call to created function:

   ```
   ChkBlankTextBoxes(txt_userID, textBoxtype);

   ChkBlankTextBoxes(txt_password, textBoxtype);
   ```