# Check for empty textboxes using C# function

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

I have written a function to check if any textboxes on a form are blank. 
It currently works if I add it to the TextBox 'leave' event.

I tried adding it to a button click event but it gives an error (`NullReferenceException unhandled`).

Below is the code:

```
public void inputBlank(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox userInput;
        userInput = sender as TextBox;
        userTextBox = userInput.Text;
        string blankBoxName = userInput.Name;
        string blankBox = blankBoxName.Remove(0,3);

        if (userTextBox == "")
        {
            errWarning.SetError(userInput, "Please enter a value for " + blankBox);
            userInput.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            errWarning.SetError(userInput, "");
        }
    }
```

Just wondering if you could advise me how to fix it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Wrong *sender*, it is a Button, not a TextBox.

Answer (score 5):

You want to validate an empty textbox in Windows application? Better to use it in Validating / Validate event.

```
private void sampleTextbox8_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    e.Cancel = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text);
    errorProvider1.SetError(textbox, "String cannot be empty");
}

private void sampleTextbox8_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    errorProvider1.SetError(textbox, string.Empty);
}
```

These links may help you

1. [Validating WinForms TextBox (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048710/validating-winforms-textbox-in-c)
2. [WinForm UI Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/winform-ui-validation)

Answer (score 3):

The direct problem, as I see it, is you're binding that event to a button which is trying to cast sender to a text input. Because the sender becomes a button control and not a textbox, you'll receive the nullreferenceexception.

If you're looking for something click-related you have a few options:

- Hard-code a list of control you'd like to validate and refactor your check function to accept the control you're validating (in fact I would refactor this way anyways).
- [recursively] iterate over the controls within the form (using maybe [this.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) and passing the `Controls` property for each container element). Then, once again, pass these controls you find that you want to validate back to the validation method.

e.g.

```
// your validation method accepting the control
private void ValidateTextBox(TextBox textbox)
{
  // validation code here
}

// bind to click event for button
private void btnValidate_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // you can do manual reference:
  List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBoxes>();
  textboxes.AddRange(new[]{
    this.mytextbox,
    this.mysecondtextbox,
    ...
  });
  //---or---
  // Use recursion and grab the textbox controls (maybe using the .Tag to flag this is
  // on you'd like to validate)
  List<TextBox> textboxes = FindTextBoxes(this.Controls);

  //---then---
  // iterate over these textboxes and validate them
  foreach (TextBox textbox in textboxes)
    ValidateTextBox(textbox);
}
```

And to give you an idea of the recursive control grab:

```
private List<TextBox> FindTextBoxes(ControlsCollection controls)
{
  List<TextBox> matches = new List<TextBox>();
  foreach (Control control in collection)
  {
    // it's a textbox
    if (control is TextBox)
      matches.Add(control as TextBox);
    // it's a container with more controls (recursion)
    else if (control is Panel) // do this for group boxes, etc. too
      matches.AddRange((control as Panel).Controls);

    // return result
    return matches;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
//This is a class property of the form itself. 
public bool IsValid { get; set; }

private void ValidateForm()
{
    Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

    func = (controls) =>
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
            if (control is TextBox)
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
                    this.IsValid = false;
            else
                func(control.Controls);
    };

    func(Controls);
}
```

You iterate through the controls, check if it's a textbox, if the .Text is empty set the class variable of IsValid to false.

Then on a button click or something is the .IsValid of the form is false, fire an error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, this would seem to be because the `sender` instance is a `Button` and not a `TextBox`, which is what you try to say it is in the following line:

```
userInput = sender as TextBox;
```

This won't work because the button you clicked is the control that triggered the event, hence why that control will be the sender.

Since `TextBox` control has (or is at least expected to have) a predefined name / identifier, why don't you just access is explicitly? As in:

```
theNameOfTheTextBox.Text
```