# How to force user to enter value in a database field

Tags: c#, sql-server, window

With my Application, i want to make sure if user enter no value in a textbox, and click on the
save button to send data in the sqlserver db.The database side validation prevent this violation and set ErrorMessage which my application will catch and Display a meaninful Message
to the User. For each required field i set it to NOT NULL. But when i test,i can still enter
enter empty textbox values it gets inserted with out value.
what am i missing?

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=abcdef;Initial Catalog=HMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sysad;Password=abcdef";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

        string SelectStatement = "SELECT * FROM tablename where RegistrationNo = @RegistrationNo";
        SqlCommand insertcommand = new SqlCommand(SelectStatement, connection);
        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNo", textBox10.Text);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            reader = insertcommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox11.Text = reader["RegistrationNo"].ToString();
                textBox1.Text = reader["Appearance"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = reader["VolumePH"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = reader["Mobility"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = reader["Viability"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = reader["Head"].ToString();
                textBox6.Text = reader["MiddlePiece"].ToString();
                textBox7.Text = reader["Tail"].ToString();
                textBox8.Text = reader["SpermCount"].ToString();
                dateTimePicker1.Text = reader["Date"].ToString();
                textBox9.Text = reader["Comment"].ToString();



            }//end while
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }//end catch
```

Comment: I would guess that an empty string gets inserted in the database, something that does not violate the NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: TextBox has not NULL value, they have empty value. Empty value is not equal to NULL, so the violation is not raised on DB.

Comment: In Win App, You can check for empty textbox through validations. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605687/1004522) is the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am i missing?

I think you are missing a distinction between `null` and an empty string.

Databases distinguish between `null` and `empty`. If your `ToString` succeeds, then you have a non-null string there, and so DB is happy to accept it as a valid value.

In general, using DB for user-side validation is somewhat wasteful: if you know that the field must not be empty, you should check for it in the UI; DB validation should serve as the last resort that preserves the integrity of your data model.

Comment: "Databases distinguish between null and empty." Not all databases are created equal.  E.g. MS SQL DBs do, Oracle SQL DBs do not.  ecomma is using MS SQL, so your statement is true in his case, just not in all.

Comment: @TimS. Well, Oracle is in a league of their own: they made a decision years ago, and decided to stick to it in the face of standards saying otherwise (that's what `2` in `VARCHAR2` is about). Here is a [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=456874&start=0&tstart=0) that discusses the subject at great length (literally: it's five pages long).

Answer (score 1):

You can use requiredfield validator in the Server side code and validate. If it is empty string return error there itself.

Going to sql server and throwing error is bad.

```
if(txtBox.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
  //throw "cannot be null error to user;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a good idea is to check the fields when you press the button. Example:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArg e){
   if (textbox1.Text == ""){
      MessageBox.Show("Your message to the user");
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Its better to check the user input in the user interface. If the user have to enter some value  you should check it before trying to insert it to the database.